# Delphi Android Location Sensor not working if location allowed after application start

Tags: android, delphi, location, firemonkey, android-sensors

I have an interesting issue with `TLocationSensor`. If the location is allowed in the Android menu before I start my application, the sensor works fine. I catch the event `OnLocationChange`. But if I don't allow location in the Android menu and start the application and then allow location in the Android menu the sensor doesn't work.

Event `OnLocationChange` is not called.

Set `LocationSensor1.Active := true;` doesn't help in this case.

How can I automatically allow location after my application starts?

I am using `Delphi XE10.1 Berlin` and `Android 6.0`

Comment: start the LocationSensor1 from a timer event and disable the timer after.  And enable the Timer in the FormCreate event

Comment: This is peculiar. I tried this out myself. I started the app, which has the location sensor set `Active` at design time, with the location settings disabled on the device. Then when the app was running I enabled the location settings. Sure enough, as expected the `onLocationChanged` method in the `JLocationListener` implementation in System.Android.Sensor.pas called `TCustomLocationSensor.DoLocationChanged`, which in turn called my  location sensor's `OnLocationChanged` event handler. I wonder what is different in your case. You have tried a trivial self-contained example, like I have done?

Comment: I make few tests. Sometimes sensor start works but in many cases not. I dont understand this behavior.
Chance to sensor start work is higger if I allow Location immediately after application starts.
Location sensor is still set as Active !

Comment: I found this same problem when running the Delphi sample OrientationSensor on Android. Only one 0.00 / NaN sensor reading is received. In order to deal with API level 26 permissions, you cannot set active := true at design time, so there is no way to start the sensor

Comment: What do u mean by no way to start the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Battled the same issue today. Manually setting the app permissions did the job in my case

Edit: Manually added to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Could you explain this with more detail?

Comment: I modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

With recent android versions it is necessary to request the permissions during runtime (on start or maybe better if and when you need it).

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
uses
  System.Permissions,
  Androidapi.JNI.OS; 

PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([
  JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
  JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)],
  procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
  begin
    if (Length(AGrantResults) <> 2)
      or (AGrantResults[0] <> TPermissionStatus.Granted)
      or (AGrantResults[1] <> TPermissionStatus.Granted) then 
      Log('Location permissions not granted');
  end);
{$ENDIF}
```

Of course, both permissions also have to be checked in project options, but this is already the default.